# Capturing http status codes with scrapy spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy. I am writing a spider designed to check a long list of urls for the server status codes and, where appropriate, what URLs they are redirected to. Importantly, if there is a chain of redirects, I need to know the status code and url at each jump. I am using  response.meta['redirect_urls'] to capture the urls, but am unsure how to capture the status codes - there doesn't seem to be a response meta key for it.

I realise I may need to write some custom middlewear to expose these values but am not quite clear how to log the status codes for every hop, nor how to access these values from the spider. I've had a look but can't find an example of anyone doing this. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

For example,

```
    items = []
    item = RedirectItem()
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['redirected_urls'] = response.meta['redirect_urls']     
    item['status_codes'] = #????
    items.append(item)
```

**Edit** - Based on feedback from warawauk and some really proactive help from the guys on the IRC channel (freenode #scrappy) I've managed to do this. I believe it's a little hacky so any comments for improvement welcome:

(1) Disable the default middleware in the settings, and add your own:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': None,
    'myproject.middlewares.CustomRedirectMiddleware': 100,
}
```

(2) Create your CustomRedirectMiddleware in your middlewares.py. It inherits from the main redirectmiddleware class and captures the redirect:

```
class CustomRedirectMiddleware(RedirectMiddleware):
    """Handle redirection of requests based on response status and meta-refresh html tag"""

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        #Get the redirect status codes
        request.meta.setdefault('redirect_status', []).append(response.status)
        if 'dont_redirect' in request.meta:
            return response
        if request.method.upper() == 'HEAD':
            if response.status in [301, 302, 303, 307] and 'Location' in response.headers:
                redirected_url = urljoin(request.url, response.headers['location'])
                redirected = request.replace(url=redirected_url)

                return self._redirect(redirected, request, spider, response.status)
            else:
                return response

        if response.status in [302, 303] and 'Location' in response.headers:
            redirected_url = urljoin(request.url, response.headers['location'])
            redirected = self._redirect_request_using_get(request, redirected_url)
            return self._redirect(redirected, request, spider, response.status)

        if response.status in [301, 307] and 'Location' in response.headers:
            redirected_url = urljoin(request.url, response.headers['location'])
            redirected = request.replace(url=redirected_url)
            return self._redirect(redirected, request, spider, response.status)

        if isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
            interval, url = get_meta_refresh(response)
            if url and interval < self.max_metarefresh_delay:
                redirected = self._redirect_request_using_get(request, url)
                return self._redirect(redirected, request, spider, 'meta refresh')


        return response
```

(3) You can now access the list of redirects in your spider with

```
request.meta['redirect_status']
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 12):

I believe that's available as

```
response.status
```

See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response

Comment: Thanks for your response lindelof. My difficulty is that typical usage of response.status  gives you the response status of the final response, after all redirects. I need response.status for every hop and I'm not clear on how to capture all of them. Does that make sense?

Comment: You could as well append the statuscode the same way you apparently populate the ['redirect_urls'] ;)

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood. Then I think you need to subclass `scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.SpiderMiddleware` according to http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/spider-middleware.html#writing-your-own-spider-middleware and override `process_spider_input` to append the intermediate status codes to, say, `response.meta['status_codes']` which should be initialized as an empty list. But I haven't tried this.

Comment: Thanks Sjaak. That is the ideal, however, I am not populating request.meta['redirect_urls'] - this is populated somewhere by default scrapy middleware. It is a request.meta special key  -[scrapy request-response docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html). The documentation there states that the meta field can contain arbitrary data but I'm not sure how to extend it to capture the response.status for every redirect.

Comment: Thanks lindelof. I'm following you, and have tried a couple of variations.  My problem is that I am failing to instantiate the response.meta['status_codes'] for some (probably very simple) reason. I get a exceptions.KeyError: 'status_codes'.  Would you have any advice on what to add to the below to address this? class RedirectMiddleware(object):
       
def process_spider_input(response, spider):
        response.meta['status_codes'].append(response.status)

Comment: You probably need to initialize the `meta` dictionary's entry for the `status_codes` key:      `if 'status_codes' in meta:          meta['status_codes'].append(XXX)      else:          meta['status_codes'] = [XXXX]`

Answer (score 4):

`response.meta['redirect_urls'` is populated by [RedirectMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect). Your spider callback will never receive responses in between, only the last one after all redirects.

If you want to control the process, subclass `RedirectMiddleware`, disable the original one, and enable yours. Then you can control the redirection process, including tracking the response statuses.

Here is the original implementation (scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect.RedirectMiddleware):

```
class RedirectMiddleware(object):
    """Handle redirection of requests based on response status and meta-refresh html tag"""

    def _redirect(self, redirected, request, spider, reason):
        ...
            redirected.meta['redirect_urls'] = request.meta.get('redirect_urls', []) + \
                [request.url]
```

As you see `_redirect` method which is called from different parts creates `meta['redirect_urls']`

And in the `process_response` method `return self._redirect(redirected, request, spider, response.status)` is called, meaning that the original response is not passed to the spider.

Comment: Thanks warwaruk, that makes sense. I was looking at the redirectmiddleware. I think I can reverse engineer this part. I think I'm still missing something here though as this class references request.meta.get['redirect_urls'] so I'm thinking the values are being passed through for each request. This makes sense also, but I can't find where that is actually happening. I'll edit my original post to see if I can clarify where I am struggling

Comment: @user1449163, this middleware is the one which creates `meta['redirect_urls']` - see the update to the answer

Answer (score 0):

KISS solution: I thought it was better to add the strict minimum of code for capturing the new redirect field, and let RedirectMiddleware do the rest:

```
from scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect import RedirectMiddleware

class CustomRedirectMiddleware(RedirectMiddleware):
  """Handle redirection of requests based on response status and meta-refresh html tag"""

  def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    #Get the redirect status codes
    request.meta.setdefault('redirect_status', []).append(response.status)
    response = super(CustomRedirectMiddleware, self).process_response(request, response, spider)
    return response
```

Then, subclassing BaseSpider, you may access the redirect_status with the following:

```
    def parse(self, response):
      item = ScrapyGoogleindexItem()
      item['redirections'] = response.meta.get('redirect_times', 0)
      item['redirect_status'] = response.meta['redirect_status']
      return item
```