# HTTP Response code for each URL while scraping through Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, response, http-response-codes

The number of URLs that are getting scraped and that are getting 200 response status is not same. Also, I want to get the URLs with their respective responses.  I am scraping 70,000 URLs using Scrapy, along with which I want to get the HTTP response status for each URL by Scrapy so that after getting the content for particular URL, we'll also get the response code for that URL:

URL, CONTENT, RESPONSE CODE

How to get the response codes for respective URLs?[image]

Comment: What is your specific question? And where can we see the code you are writing about?

Comment: The 'status' property of your Response class instance should be what you need. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scrapy/scrapy_requests_and_responses.htm for further details. Also see the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982417/capturing-http-status-codes-with-scrapy-spider

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing http status codes with scrapy spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982417/capturing-http-status-codes-with-scrapy-spider)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by default Scrapy doesn't call your callbacks if an error response code is returned to the spider. To make sure your callbacks are called even for response codes such as `404`, `500`, etc, you have to pass these two keys in the request `meta` argument:

- [`handle_httpstatus_all`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html?highlight=handle_httpstatus_all#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror): when `True`, scrapy won't treat an invalid response code as an error, and will call your callback to handle such response.
- [`dont_retry`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry): when `True`, scrapy won't retry the request when a retriable response is fetched.

Your spider could be something along these lines:

```
class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yourspider'
    your_list_of_urls = [
        ...
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.your_list_of_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url,
                callback=self.parse_info,
                meta={
                    'handle_httpstatus_all': True,
                    'dont_retry': True,
                },
            )

    def parse_info(self, response):
        yield {
            'url': response.url,
            'content': response.text,
            'status': response.status,
        }
```

Comment: Is there any way where we can see which URL got which response code?

Comment: run `scrapy crawl yourspider -o items.json` and check the items.json file after it finishes.